# In Python, how to parse a string representing a set of keyword arguments such that the order does not matter

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm writing a class `RecurringInterval` which - based on the [dateutil.rrule](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) object - represents a recurring interval in time. I have defined a custom, human-readable `__str__` method for it and would like to also define a `parse` method which (similar to the [rrulestr()](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-e987b581aebacf25c7276d3e9214385a12a091f2) function) parses the string back into an object.

Here is the `parse` method and some test cases to go with it:

```
import re
from dateutil.rrule import FREQNAMES
import pytest

class RecurringInterval(object):
    freq_fmt = "{freq}"
    start_fmt = "from {start}"
    end_fmt = "till {end}"
    byweekday_fmt = "by weekday {byweekday}"
    bymonth_fmt = "by month {bymonth}"

    @classmethod
    def match_pattern(cls, string):
        SPACES = r'\s*'

        freq_names = [freq.lower() for freq in FREQNAMES] + [freq.title() for freq in FREQNAMES]        # The frequencies may be either lowercase or start with a capital letter
        FREQ_PATTERN = '(?P<freq>{})?'.format("|".join(freq_names))

        # Start and end are required (their regular expressions match 1 repetition)
        START_PATTERN = cls.start_fmt.format(start=SPACES + r'(?P<start>.+?)')
        END_PATTERN = cls.end_fmt.format(end=SPACES + r'(?P<end>.+?)')

        # The remaining tokens are optional (their regular expressions match 0 or 1 repetitions)
        BYWEEKDAY_PATTERN = cls.optional(cls.byweekday_fmt.format(byweekday=SPACES + r'(?P<byweekday>.+?)'))
        BYMONTH_PATTERN = cls.optional(cls.bymonth_fmt.format(bymonth=SPACES + r'(?P<bymonth>.+?)'))

        PATTERN = SPACES + FREQ_PATTERN \
                + SPACES + START_PATTERN \
                + SPACES + END_PATTERN \
                + SPACES + BYWEEKDAY_PATTERN \
                + SPACES + BYMONTH_PATTERN \
                + SPACES + "$"                  # The character '$' is needed to make the non-greedy regular expressions parse till the end of the string

        return re.match(PATTERN, string).groupdict()

    @staticmethod
    def optional(pattern):
        '''Encloses the given regular expression in an optional group (i.e., one that matches 0 or 1 repetitions of the original regular expression).'''
        return '({})?'.format(pattern)  


'''Tests'''
def test_match_pattern_with_byweekday_and_bymonth():
    string = "Weekly from 2017-11-03 15:00:00 till 2017-11-03 16:00:00 by weekday Monday, Tuesday by month January, February"

    groups = RecurringInterval.match_pattern(string)
    assert groups['freq'] == "Weekly"
    assert groups['start'].strip() == "2017-11-03 15:00:00"
    assert groups['end'].strip() == "2017-11-03 16:00:00"
    assert groups['byweekday'].strip() == "Monday, Tuesday"
    assert groups['bymonth'].strip() == "January, February"

def test_match_pattern_with_bymonth_and_byweekday():
    string = "Weekly from 2017-11-03 15:00:00 till 2017-11-03 16:00:00 by month January, February by weekday Monday, Tuesday "

    groups = RecurringInterval.match_pattern(string)
    assert groups['freq'] == "Weekly"
    assert groups['start'].strip() == "2017-11-03 15:00:00"
    assert groups['end'].strip() == "2017-11-03 16:00:00"
    assert groups['byweekday'].strip() == "Monday, Tuesday"
    assert groups['bymonth'].strip() == "January, February"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # pytest.main([__file__])
    pytest.main([__file__+"::test_match_pattern_with_byweekday_and_bymonth"])       # This passes
    # pytest.main([__file__+"::test_match_pattern_with_bymonth_and_byweekday"])     # This fails
```

Although the parser works if you specify the arguments in the 'right' order, it is 'inflexible' in that it doesn't allow the optional arguments to be given in arbitrary order. This is why the second test fails.

What would be a way to make the parser parse the 'optional' fields in any order, such that both tests pass? (I was thinking of making an iterator with all permutations of the regular expressions and trying `re.match` on each one, but this does not seem like an elegant solution).

Comment: can you cut down your code a bit? seems like an interesting question but it's just too "wall of code" for me at the moment. A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Sure, the original snippet included almost all [dateutil.rrule](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) parameters, but I've removed the ones not used in the tests to reduce the line count.

Comment: I don't have the time or insight to answer but have an upvote.

Comment: Are you fixed on the idea of using regular expressions for this, or do you just want a working parser? I suspect the two may be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, your language is getting complex enough that it's time to ditch regular expressions and learn how to use a proper parsing library. I threw this together using [pyparsing](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/), and I've annotated it heavily to try and explain what's going on, but if anything's unclear do ask and I'll try to explain.

```
from pyparsing import Regex, oneOf, OneOrMore

# Boring old constants, I'm sure you know how to fill these out...
months      = ['January', 'February']
weekdays    = ['Monday', 'Tuesday']
frequencies = ['Daily', 'Weekly']

# A datetime expression is anything matching this regex. We could split it down
# even further to get day, month, year attributes in our results object if we felt
# like it
datetime_expr = Regex(r'(\d{4})-(\d\d?)-(\d\d?) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})')

# A from or till expression is the word "from" or "till" followed by any valid datetime
from_expr = 'from' + datetime_expr.setResultsName('from_')
till_expr = 'till' + datetime_expr.setResultsName('till')

# A range expression is a from expression followed by a till expression
range_expr = from_expr + till_expr

# A weekday is any old weekday
weekday_expr = oneOf(weekdays)
month_expr = oneOf(months)
frequency_expr = oneOf(frequencies)

# A by weekday expression is the words "by weekday" followed by one or more weekdays
by_weekday_expr = 'by weekday' + OneOrMore(weekday_expr).setResultsName('weekdays')
by_month_expr = 'by month' + OneOrMore(month_expr).setResultsName('months')

# A recurring interval, then, is a frequency, followed by a range, followed by
# a weekday and a month, in any order
recurring_interval = frequency_expr + range_expr + (by_weekday_expr & by_month_expr)

# Let's parse!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = recurring_interval.parseString('Daily from 1111-11-11 11:00:00 till 1111-11-11 12:00:00 by weekday Monday by month January February')

    # Note that setResultsName causes everything to get packed neatly into
    # attributes for us, so we can pluck all the bits and pieces out with no
    # difficulty at all
    print res
    print res.from_
    print res.till
    print res.weekdays
    print res.months
```

Comment: I do agree. Regex is a nice tools that works great for simple enough parsing. But when it becomes too complex, regex only add another level of complexity. *We have a parsing problem. Just use regexes. Now there are two problems*

Comment: It seems from the term `((by_weekday_expr + by_month_expr) | (by_month_expr + by_weekday_expr))` that this method still needs you to list the possible permutations of optional arguments. In this simplified example there are only two, but for the actual application there are more like 10, which would lead to 10! = 3,628,800 permutations. I suppose these can be generated and `join`ed, but it still does not seem very elegant and might make the code slow, no?

Comment: @KurtPeek Indeed, I thought as much and then read the docs a bit harder. Take a look at the edit - `&` is the thing we need here.

Comment: Another question: you've specified a `datetime_expr` as a `Regex` which matches the datetimes in this example, but in my application I'd like to allow 'anything' (and later use [dateutil.parser](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) to parse it). How can I make the `datetime_expr` more 'flexible'? (I've tried `Regex(r'.+?')` but this leads to a `ParseException`).

Answer (score 1):

You have many options here, each with different downsides.

One approach would be to use a repeated alternation, like `(by weekday|by month)*`:

```
(?P<freq>Weekly)?\s+from (?P<start>.+?)\s+till (?P<end>.+?)(?:\s+by weekday (?P<byweekday>.+?)|\s+by month (?P<bymonth>.+?))*$
```

This will match strings of the form `week month` and `month week`, but also `week week` or `month week month` etc.

Another option would be use lookaheads, like `(?=.*by weekday)?(?=.*by month)?`:

```
 (?P<freq>Weekly)?\s+from (?P<start>.+?)\s+till (?P<end>.+?(?=$| by))(?=.*\s+by weekday (?P<byweekday>.+?(?=$| by))|)(?=.*\s+by month (?P<month>.+?(?=$| by))|)
```

However, this requires a known delimiter (I used " by") to know how far to match. Also, it'll silently ignore any extra characters (meaning it'll match strings of the form `by weekday [some gargabe] by month`).