# Python regex to match SQL INSERT statements

Tags: python, regex, django

I am working on a django website, and I am trying to use the data dumped from a legacy database to create YAML fixtures for django.

I am writing a crude SQL parser using regex (I know, I know .. but I can't find anything that will help me do this quickly, so I have to "roll my own" - unless there are better suggestions).

Part of the "rolling my own" solution is to parse the SQL statements - these are autogenerated, so the format of the statements will not change.

Here are two sample `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO ref_geographic_region (continent_id,name) VALUES(8,'Europe (Western)');
INSERT INTO ref_currency_group (name) VALUES('Major');
```

I want to grok the SQL statements into the following pattern:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> VALUES (one_or_more_alphanums_separated_by_comma);
```

I then need to match the following values:

- table_name
- one_or_more_alphanums_separated_by_comma

Here is my regex pattern. It is matching, but the grouping is not quite what I want.

```
pattern_string = r"INSERT INTO ([a-zA-Z\_]+)\s\(((([a-zA-Z\_]+)(\,)*)+)\)\s+VALUES\(([0-9]*)|([a-zA-Z\(\)']+)(\,)*\;"
```

How I can modify (and simplify) the pattern above, so it matches only the tokens I'm interested in?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the question - and you may have already tried this and found it insufficient - but would loading that SQL into a database, [running inspectdb on the database to get an initial Django model file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/), and then using `dumpdata` to turn that into fixtures help?

Comment: Consider writing a parser instead of abusing regex capture groups. I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435114/in-python-how-to-parse-a-string-representing-a-set-of-keyword-arguments-such-th/42437175#42437175. If that helps, great. If not, let me know and I'll see if I can whip up a grammar for the language you're trying to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the statements is fixed, there is little point in using regular expressions. Just use simple string parsing:

```
parts = statement.split(' ', 4)

print(parts[2])
print(parts[3][1:-1].split(','))
print(parts[4][7:-2].split(','))
```

Example output:

```
ref_geographic_region
['continent_id', 'name']
['8', "'Europe (Western)'"]
```

Comment: I like this answer.  It's the simplest approach - I don't know why it didn't occur to me...

Answer (score 4):

Stop trying to parse SQL with regex. This is roughly as bad as parsing HTML with regex, since SQL is a context-free language that regexes are ill-equipped to handle. This can be accomplished far more easily with a proper parsing module like [PyParsing](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/)

```
from pyparsing import Regex, QuotedString, delimitedList

# Object names and numbers match these regular expression
object_name = Regex('[a-zA-Z_]+')
number = Regex('-?[0-9]+')
# A string is just something with quotes around it - PyParsing has a built in
string = QuotedString("'") | QuotedString('"')

# A term is a number or a string
term = number | string

# The values we want to capture are either delimited lists of expressions we know about...
column_list = (delimitedList(object_name)).setResultsName('columns')
term_list = (delimitedList(term)).setResultsName('terms')

# Or just an expression we know about by itself
table_name = object_name.setResultsName('table')

# And an SQL statement is just all of these pieces joined together with some string between them
sql_stmt = "INSERT INTO " + table_name + "(" + column_list + ") VALUES(" + term_list + ");"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = sql_stmt.parseString("""INSERT INTO ref_geographic_region (continent_id,name) VALUES(8,'Europe (Western)');""")
    print res.table         # ref_geographic_region
    print list(res.columns) # ['continent_id', 'name']
    print list(res.terms)   # ['8', 'Europe (Western)']
```

This is a quick half-hour strawman - I'd recommend reading through its [docs](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing) and getting a proper understanding of how it works. In particular, PyParsing has some strange behaviour with whitespace that it's worth understanding before you properly strike out.

Comment: +1 for recommending PyParsing (looks like an interesting package) - I'll use it in a future project,  but I feel it's overkill for this particular problem.